# Location of changeset comments on a Team Foundation server?

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, tfsbuild

One of my colleagues is working on a Continuous Integration build script that makes a new build every time a developer makes a checkin, and sends an email out to the development team when the build finishes. We want to take any comments associated with the checkin (the same comments you'd see by right-clicking on a project file and selecting View History) and include them in the email. However, we're not sure where in the back-end of TFS to point the script so it can retrieve those comments. Does anyone know where we should look?

Comment: Have you guys not deployed the TFS Build server parts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using TFS API for that?  If so, you simply do:

```cs
TeamFoundationServer tfs = TeamFoundationServerFactory.GetServer("http://WhateverServerUrl");
IBuildServer buildServer = (IBuildServer)tfs.GetService(typeof(IBuildServer));
VersionControlServer VsServer = (VersionControlServer)tfs.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));
IBuildDetail build = buildServer.GetAllBuildDetails(new Uri("http://WhateverBuildUrl"));

List<IChangesetSummary> associatedChangesets = InformationNodeConverters.GetAssociatedChangesets(build);

foreach (IChangesetSummary changeSetData in associatedChangesets)
{
    Changeset changeSet = VsServer.GetChangeset(changeSetData.ChangesetId);
    string x = changeSet.Comment;
}
```

If you are trying to look it up in the DB, you can look at the changeset title:

```sql
USE tfs_warehouse
SELECT [ChangesetID]
      ,[ChangesetTitle]
  FROM [tfs_warehouse].[dbo].[DimChangeset]
```

From here add a where clause to either the id, date etc.

This is where that data is stored in TFS 2010.

In TFS 2008, you would use TfsWarehouse and look at dbo.ChangeSet Changset column.

Comment: We're using an MS Build script, so I'm not sure if we can use the API in that way. Do you know if that would be possible?

Comment: Just add a custom task.  Inside that custom task reference in using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client and write that code and that should do it.

Comment: If you need help on writing a custom task you can google and find a few examples but you essentially just create a project and build.  Get the dll and reference in that custom task into your MSBuild script.  Your project can of course reference the aforementioned assemblies just like any other project.